# Phonegap-navigator.back.backHistory() is not working

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I have an `index.html` page and I have called dynamic views from `index.html` page and clicked to navigate to next view. Now when I'm trying to get back to previous view from next view then my back button is not working. I am new in phonegap. Here below is my code:

index.html:

```
<a href="#" id="complaintsId" class="item-link close-panel item-content">
    <div class="item-media">
        <i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item-inner" id="Div2">
        <div class="item-title">Complaints</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

javascript:

```
var tableContent = '<div class="navbar"><div class="navbar-inner"> <div class="left"> </div>';
tableContent += '   <div class="center sliding"> </div><div class="right">';
tableContent += '<a href="#" class="link icon-   only open-panel" data-panel="right"></a></div>';
tableContent += ' </div></div><div class="view another-view"><div class="pages">';
tableContent += '<div class="page no-toolbar" data-page="blog">';
tableContent += '   <div class="page-content"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row">';
tableContent += '<div class="col-md-12 " id="DisableDiv1" style="width: 100%;"> #someText</a>';
tableContent += '</div></div></div></div> </div></div></div>';

function ComplaintsClick() {
    $("#complaintsId").on('click', function () {
        Surl = "***/api/Complaint/GetLeaderComplaint/***"";
        var abcString = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: Surl,
            type: 'GET',
            data: '',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#DisableDiv1').html("");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    abcString += ' <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#" class="btn" type="button" id="clicked_' + i + '" onClick="selectNews(' + data[i].complaintId + ')">  <h3> ' + data[i].title + ' </h3>';
                    abcString += ' <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />';
                    abcString += '<span class="commentDiscprition">' + data[i].comment + '</span> </a></div>';

                }

                $(".page-content").html('')
                var abcx = tableContent.replace('#someText', abcString);
                $(".page-content").html(abcx);
                $("table#DisableDiv1 tr:odd").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
            }
        });
    });
}


 function selectNews() {

    window.location = "ExpandNews.html";

}
```

Here I am trying to redirect to previous view:

`ExpandNews.html` page:

```
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="left">

                <a class="ui-link" href="#" rel="external" id="aa" onclick="onBackKeyDown()">
                    <img src="#" alt="Phone" border="0">
                </a>

               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
            history.go(-1);
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
```